# How to print a text progress bar when some text was in front of it in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, I mean this, here's my code:

```
def progress():                                                                                                                         
    for i in range(100):                                                        
        print('{0}\b\b'.format(i), end='', flush=True)                          
        time.sleep(0.1)                                                         

print('progress bar test: {0} finished!'.format(progress()))
```

I want the output like this:

```
progress bar test: 1.2.3..(and then print 'finished!')
```

but however I got this out put:

```
1.2.3...
progress bar test: None finished!
```

This is the question. And I also want to know if the number was smaller than 10, will the `\b\b` delete the in front text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function is not returning a value so you see `None` which is returned by default. You can return `"finished"` when your loop completes:

```
import time
def progress():
    for i in range(3):
        print('{0}.'.format(i), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return "finished!"

print('progress bar test: {0}'.format(progress()))
```

If you want to be able to change the return value just pass in an arg:

```
def progress(end):
    for i in range(3):
        print('{0}.'.format(i), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return end

print('progress bar test: {0} '.format(progress("finished!")))
```

Comment: yeah, but I want `print('progress bar test: {0}')`. And `{0}` is 1.2.3...100.

Comment: Then save the output in a variable and return that